# Finding the type of number entered by the user

Tags: beginner, android, kotlin

I am making a fractions calculator that can calculate fractions, whole numbers and mixed fractions.

So there is a String fraction, which is the input.

Also, the user will enter the fraction in a specified format which is:

- For normal fraction, "a/b" (a and b are integers)
- For whole numbers, "c" (c is an integer)
- For mixed fraction, "c a/b" (c is integer, a/b is the fraction separated by a space)

I want the program to check and find out which type of fraction the user has entered and then proceed. I'm using If-Else If-Else for this.

```
fun fractionalize(fraction: String): List<Int>{
        //Finds type of number (input) and converts to List<Int> with [numerator, denominator, whole number]
        var result: List<Int> = listOf(0,1,0)
        var numerator: Int = 0
        var denominator:Int = 1
        var whole_number:Int = 0
        try {
            if ((fraction.contains('/') && fraction.indexOf('/') == fraction.lastIndexOf('/')) && !fraction.contains(" ")) {
                //input is a regular fraction
                var fraction_string = fraction.split("/")
                numerator = fraction_string[0].toInt()
                denominator = fraction_string[1].toInt()
                result = listOf(numerator, denominator, 0)
            } else if (fraction.isDigitsOnly()) {
                //input is a whole number
                result = listOf(fraction.toInt(), 1, 0)
            } else if ((fraction.contains('/') && fraction.indexOf('/') == fraction.lastIndexOf('/')) && (fraction.contains(" ") && fraction.indexOf(' ') == fraction.lastIndexOf(' '))) {
                //input is mixed fraction
                var wholeNumber_split = fraction.split(" ")
                whole_number = wholeNumber_split[0].toInt()
                numerator = wholeNumber_split[1].split("/")[0].toInt()
                numerator += whole_number * denominator
                denominator = wholeNumber_split[1].split("/")[1].toInt()
                result = listOf(numerator, denominator, 0)
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                "The number you entered is not in a valid format.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            //simplifying input
            if (result[2] != 0){
                numerator += whole_number * denominator
                result = listOf(numerator, denominator, 0)
            }
            return result
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                "The number you entered is not in a valid format.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return result
        }
    }
```

Is this the best way I can do that or is there cleaner and more efficient code I can make (personally I think this is too messy and can be made more efficient)?

Comment: A regular expression is the first thing that comes to my mind when I have to check if input matches a certain pattern. It would allow you to check full validity of the input, not just if it contains a '/' character. E.g. 'a/3' would be rejected immediately.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen So what should I keep as parameters?

Comment: Please adjust the title of your "question" to confirm to [this site's standards](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several areas where it can be improved.

The first is that you should separate the parsing code from the platform code (`Toast`). Kotlin has a great testing framework, in which it is easy to write "parsing `"1 2/3"` should return `listOf(1, 2, 3)`". This testing code works best if you run it directly on your developing machine, and without any `Toast` or `Activity`.

The next thing is that you should not use `List<Int>` in places where you originally wanted to say `Fraction` or maybe, to be more specific, `MixedFraction`. The point is that `listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` is a valid list but not a valid fraction. By using a specifically constrained type you force the Kotlin compiler to check your code for you.

```kotlin
class Fraction(
    val int: Int,
    val num: Int,
    val den: Int
)
```

To make your parser extensible to expressions that are more complicated, you must not use `contains`. Instead, the best-practice way is to split the input into tokens first (often using regular expressions) and then to combine these tokens to expression trees (using [a parser that only looks at the very next token to decide what to do next](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_LR_parser)). The details of all of this are covered in any good book on compiler construction.

In your case, the tokens would be:

- unsigned integer
- fraction slash
- unary minus sign

Note that there is no "space" token, as that is usually left out when defining an expression language.

Comment: I am fairly new to android development, so I don't understand a lot of things you told me.....Making a Fraction class is a great idea. I don't get making the parser thing. Please help me. Also, I'll edit the code to include the whole function.

Comment: Just google for "kotlin testing", and you should find a tutorial for that topic. Invest some time in this topic since testing is a fundamental requirement to writing reliable and robust code.

Comment: Please, don't answer incomplete questions. Now there are 2 options: either you remove the remark about the code being incomplete or we rollback the added code. I'll leave it up to you which is preferred. Thank you.

Comment: @Mast I think removing the remark would be better.

Comment: @DeathVenom Next time, please make sure the first revision of your question is complete. We don't deal well with snippets, as indicated in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Hey can you please explain 'splitting the input into tokens' or point me to a resource/tutorial? I don't get that part.